# STOMP protocol implementation with Kafka

Tags: java, websocket, apache-kafka, stomp, spring-kafka

I'm developing a chat module for a web plateform using the websocket protocol, and STOMP as a message protocol.

It's my first time using any message broker, and Kafka is the one used on the company's (the one i'm working for) web plateform, for other modules I guess. And having previously worked with RabbitMQ when I was just starting, now I have to switch to Kafka. I saw on RabbitMQ's website there's a whole article about how to use STOMP, but there is no such thing on Kafka's official website.

But I've explored several other sources, many tutorials and I couldn't find anything relevant about using STOMP protocol with Kafka, which leads me to ask if it's possible ?

Here's my websocket configuration class :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");

//Here's the line I wrote to use Kafka as a MB, but doesn't work        
registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost("localhost").setRelayPort(9092);
```

After lauching Kafka, and then running my Java Spring app, I get a "connection reset by peer" from a java.io.IOException, which is not supposed to be thrown if everything works fine.

I'm using Kakfa's 2.2.0 release, Zookeeper's 3.4.14 release, and using STS 3 as my IDE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you might have just copied this? https://medium.com/@amit.dhodi/routing-kafka-messages-to-browser-over-web-socket-e4d0cf4150a9 or https://github.com/sulthan309/Live-Dashboard-using-Kafka-and-Spring-Websocket

Comment: well this is the basic implementation for websocket config based on another tutorial (neither of the two you mentioned), but it's pretty much the same for all of them anyway.

Comment: Well, the second one shows a video of it working. So, somewhere something is misconfigured on your side... You've not shown your Kafka configuration or other Spring code for it, but Kafka isn't a "relay host"

Comment: so you're telling me there's a chance that I can somehow make it work ? because below another man answered, and said that Kafka has no support for STOMP protocol. And given that man resumé, I would very much believe him.

Comment: By the way, the guy in the video doesn't use Kafka as a message broker, he instead uses a simple (basic) one that's provided by Spring. Unless there is something I didn't really understand.

Comment: Gary below is one of the lead developers in Spring, yes... My point was that you would have to *consume* from Kafka, then deserialize the request, then *forward* the message to a WebSocket channel. Kafka has no **built-in** support, but that doesn't stop you from consuming on one end of Kafka, then forwarding to a destination of your choice.... The video 1) starts Zookeeper and Kafka 2) Starts his app (a Kafka consumer and websocket producer) 3) Produces data into Kafka just using console producer 4) Waits for the WebSocket to receive the messages... Seems convincing to me.

Comment: See this section that uses `SimpMessagingTemplate` within the KafkaService https://github.com/sulthan309/Live-Dashboard-using-Kafka-and-Spring-Websocket/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springKafka/liveDashboard/services/KafkaConsumerService.java#L15-L20

Comment: I kind of understand, but I'm not sure that solution is the one for me, because I need to use STOMP as a messaging protocol. So since it's impossible with Kafka, I will have to go back to RabbitMQ. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think there's any way around it.

Comment: @Dan did you find anything solid in this regard?

Answer (score 5):

RabbitMQ doesn't natively support STOMP, but it has a STOMP plugin; Kafka has no built-in support for STOMP.